# How to draw circuit on stackexchange electronic

Tags: discussion

Is there a way to draw circuit directly on stackexchange other than upload the picture file ? What are some of the free programs you use to draw the circuit which will be uploaded on stackExchange

Comment: the button with diode, capacitor, resistor and pencil on it, next to the mountain view

Comment: ... or just hit ctrl-M while in the editor.

Comment: Thank you very much Dave and Neil